# GD script fails to process all images in array

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I've been building a gallery in php as a learning exercise and also because I'll need one to display my wedding photos in a couple of months.

I have written a function that processes the images. It looks to see what images are in the original folder and generates a thumbnail and preview for each.  It's worked fine up until now as I've been testing with small batches of images.

Now I have 24 images in the original folder it only process the first 18. I don't get any errors displayed it just seems to stop.

Function

```
function processImgs($previewWidth, $thumbWidth, $thumbPath, $previewPath, $originalPath) {

    $images = glob($originalPath."*");

    foreach($images as $image){

    $path_parts = pathinfo($image);

    // setup filenames
    $thumbFile = $thumbPath . "thumb_" . $path_parts['filename'] . ".jpg";
    $previewFile = $previewPath . "preview_" . $path_parts['filename'] . ".jpg";

    // calculate new images sizes
    $size = getimagesize($image);
    $originalWidth = $size['0'];
    $originalHeight = $size['1'];
    $previewHeight = $originalHeight / ($originalWidth / $previewWidth);
    $thumbHeight = $originalHeight / ($originalWidth / $thumbWidth);

    //create new images
    $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    $preview = imagecreatetruecolor($previewWidth, $previewHeight);
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($preview, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $previewWidth, $previewHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);

    // save images to their new folders
        imagejpeg($preview, $previewFile);
        imagejpeg($thumb, $thumbFile);
        imagedestroy($original);
        imagedestroy($preview);
        imagedestroy($thumb);

    // give some feedback when the script runs
      if (file_exists($thumbFile) && file_exists($previewFile)) {
        echo ". " . $path_parts['filename'] . " processed successfully.<br>";
      } else {
        echo ". " . $path_parts['filename'] . " <strong>failed.</strong><br>";
      }
    }
}
```

I call the function like this

```
processImgs(1200, 400, "thumb/", "preview/", "original/");
```

I don't know why it doesn't work with more files. Is there a time limit that I could be hitting? It does take a while. I'm currently building this locally on MAMP.

---

### UPDATE

Mike was correct, the function was timing out. His solution is much more suitable.

I have now created a script that does what he suggested and it has solved the problem. Thanks for the help. I've added the script below in case it's of use to others.

```
$newWidth = 400;

if (isset($_GET['img']))     {

    $img = $_GET['img'];
    $filename = $img . ".jpg";

    if (file_exists($filename)) {

        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;

    } else {

        $originalFile = "../original/" . $filename;
        $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalFile);
        $size = getimagesize($originalFile);
        $newHeight = $size['1'] / ( $size['0'] / $newWidth);
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($new, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $size['0'], $size['1']);
        imagejpeg($new, $filename);
        imagedestroy($original);
        imagedestroy($new);

        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
        fpassthru($fp);
    }

}
```

Comment: PHP has a default execution time limit after which it will just...stop. You can change the value by editing PHP.INI if you have access to that. A better approach is check whether a thumbnail has been generated when it's requested and generate it then. Subsequent requests will get the already created version.

Comment: _I don't get any errors displayed_, have you turned on error reporting? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`